# Improper Integral $\int _ {0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}} dx $

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Does the following improper integral converges?
$$\int _ {0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}} dx $$
I have tried some approaches but I'm not sure whether it was correct or not.

First I split the integral since there are 2 critical points at $x=0$ and $x=1$:

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}}dx = \int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}}dx + \int_{a}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}}dx$$
>   For the first part, I notice that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}} $$
>   So I consider the limit
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}} = 1 $$
>
> Now we know that $\int_{0}^{a}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}}dx$ coverges (the reason is that we know that from $x=0$ to $a$ the following inequality holds:
>   $ \frac{\sin{a}}{a} x < \sin{x}\rightarrow \int_{0}^{a}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}}dx < \int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{\frac{a}{\sin{a}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}dx$, and the right hand side term converges since it's a p-series with $p=0.5$). Consequently, by LCT, the $\int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}}dx$ converges.

For the second part, similarly. At $x=1$,

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{1}}}$$
>   So I consider the limit
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) }}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{1}}} $$
>
> Now we know that $\int_{a}^{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}}dx$ coverges (by Integral Test). Consequently, by LCT, the $\int_{a}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}}dx$ converges.
>   For these reasons, the improper integral converges.

If it is correct, I still don't understand how it really works. I just follow the approach in this [link](http://www.phengkimving.com/calc_of_one_real_var/11_more_on_the_intgrl/11_03_tests_for_conv_of_improper_intgrl.htm) (at the end of the page, problem 5).

**So my question is:**

Is this idea correct? Can I to compare the improper integral by using LCT in this way? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: On both ends, the function is essentially $1/\sqrt x$, which integrates as $\sqrt x$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get the idea. Could you please describe a little bit more ? I'm not good at calculus.

Comment: I find the definition of LCT in this way: If the positive functions f(x) and g(x) are continuous on $[a,\infty)$, and if
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L $$
, $0<L<\infty$
then $\int _ {a}^{\infty} f(x) dx $ and $\int _ {a}^{\infty} g(x) dx $ both diverge or both converge.

Comment: But in this case, the integral in the question is from $x=0$ to $x=1$ and I don't know how to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int _ {0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}}  =\\\int _ {0}^{\epsilon} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}} +
\int _ {\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}} +
\int _ {1-\epsilon}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}} \approx\\
\int _ {0}^{\epsilon} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} +
\int _ {\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x) \sin{x}}} +
\frac1{\sqrt{\sin(1)}}\int _ {1-\epsilon}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}.$$

All three integrals are finite.